# Does it exist a sequence with this characteristic?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergence-operator

If the distance between two consecutive terms decreases, **the sequence is oscillating amortized,** it is to say:
$$|X_{t+2}-X_{t+1}|<|X_{t+1}-X_{t}|  $$ For any t.

**Does it exist a diverge-oscillating-amortized sequence?**

Comment: What is " diverge-oscillating-amortized"?

Comment: Can you take simply $X_t$ to be $1/2^t$?

Comment: Yes but $1/2^t$ converges because the limit exist and is 0. I need to find one that not converges.

Comment: I don't think anyone understood what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, what about $(\ln(n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: Or the square root, cube root, etc.